# How to merge or combine results from a query

Tags: t-sql

I have the a query that returns count of items sold from current and prior month from different states.

```
   States    Prior Month   Current Month
1    CA           1              2   
2    NY           8              4
```

How would I go about merging/combining the two resulting row into something like this:

```
       States      Prior Month    Current Month
   1 Other States      9               4
```

Or is this something I have to do during the query? Any information on how I should tackle this problem would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your current query is correct and does what you want you can wrap it up in an outer SELECT like this

```
SELECT 1, 
       'Other States' States, 
       SUM([Prior Month]) 'Prior Month', 
       SUM([Current Month]) 'Current Month'
FROM 
(
   -- Put your current query here 
) t
```